# How to make Image within jQuery sortable Element draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm wondering it there's any jQuery wizards out there that can help me out!

I have a list of sortable elements that will act as "photoshop" layers, and within those elements there is an image element.

Before I put the image within the Sortable element, I could drag it onto canvas and draw it at that position, but now when I drag, I drag the whole sortable element.

```
<ul id = "layers">
<li class = "layer" id = "0">
<img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="imgnumber0" class="draggable-img" src="toolongtocopy!!">
</li>
<li class = "layer" id = "1">
<img draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="imgnumber1" class="draggable-img" src="toolongtocopy!!">
</li>
</ul>
```

My script :

```
 $(function() {
    $('#layerslist').sortable({

        update: function(event, ui) {
            var result = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            alert(result);
            }
    });

});
```

I'm wondering how I would allow the image element to be draggable separately from the sortable li?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the image to happen?

Comment: I just want to be able to drag that separately to the sortable element that contains it. I have a function to allow it to be dropped within a HTML canvas and be drawn at that point.

Comment: So you have two things to sort? There's a sortable inside another parent sortable?

Comment: No, when I select and drag the image right now the whole sortable element drags. I just want the image to drag if I click on that, but if I click anywhere else within the sortable element I'd like to be able to drag and drop to sort within the list of elements.

Comment: Whole sortable element drags **

Comment: Hey!!! I know hwo to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [Handles](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle). Specify the handle as this way:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  handle: "p"
});
```

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for thank you for that though! I want to drag the image element OUT OF the sortable element

Comment: @iAsk Have a browser through other options. I am sure there is an option.